# The opposite of "gift"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Is there a noun for the opposite of "gift"?  I want to use in a context like, "A kind word can be a gift but a kind word said in malice is not a gift.  It is a ____." Something that means like a gifting debit, a withdrawal rather than a contribution.  What is a good noun for this?

Comment: How about a **theft**?

Comment: Liability, obligation, deficit, invoice, albatross, assessment.

Comment: And, probably the most obvious for that specific context, *theft*.

Comment: I would do away with *kind* all together in the second part:  "A kind word is like a gift, but a word said in malice is like a knife"

Comment: How about "grift"?

Answer (score 4):

A *Trojan Horse* is a "gift" given with malicious intent. If you have ever heard of Trojan programs, they are called that for this specific reason.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trojan_Horse

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trojan_horse_(computing)

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few antonyms for gift, and the two which seem most appropriate are, 'penalty' and 'fine', however, they don't really fit with your context.

in your context, "A kind word can be a gift but a kind word said in malice is not a gift. It is a ____."

I would use an antonym of 'blessing'; either 'curse' or 'scourge'.

"A kind word can be a gift but a kind word said in malice is not a gift. It is a scourge."

Answer (score 0):

The courts can *tax* someone to punish them.

> Now, as the most common of litigation tactics, some motions to **tax** costs are spurned out of the need for firms big and small ones to recoup money spent defending non-meritorious cases.

[Source](https://www.americanbar.org/groups/litigation/committees/minority-trial-lawyer/practice/2017/042817-what-you-should-know-about-taxation-of-costs/)

When a court *taxes* a party, they take money from that party as a punishment for bringing a case without merit.

In contrast with a *gift*, a *tax* removes something from someone. There probably is no perfect opposite to *gift*.

> A kind word said in malice is not a gift. It is a *tax*.

Comment: This must be British; I do not recall this usage of "tax" in the US.  Here, the court may *fine* someone to punish them,

Comment: I was referring to a term in US jurisprudence. A court *fine* may punish someone who has shown contempt, for instance. This is to deter illegal or infelicitous behavior. When a court *taxes* someone, it is a punishment for frivolus, but procedurally legal behavior. I have seen courts *tax* parties for wasting its time by dealing with matters already dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

Debt, burden, obligation.

"A kind word can be a gift but a kind word said in malice is not a gift. It is a **burden**."